# How to Resize or place the image in PDF after it is converted from SVG using Apache Batik

Tags: apache, pdf, svg, batik, rasterizing

I am using apache batik to convert SVG to PDF. I was successfully able to convert from SVG to PDF. The result looks to be fine. But I am facing issue to place the converted image properly in the PDF. I need something like formatting, resizing the image and add some margins when it is generated with PDF so that I can place it in the center of PDF. I am not sure which is a proper option in Apache Batik. Can anyone please guide how to fix this issue ? Currently I am using the below code.

```
TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(svgHtml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(pdfOutputStream);
int dpi = 300;
transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(dpi * 8.67));
transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, new Float(dpi * 11.69));
transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_PIXEL_UNIT_TO_MILLIMETER,(25.4f / 72f));
transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput, transcoderOutput);
```